# Table of content as right side growing tree

Tags: table-of-contents, trees, tikz-qtree

How to prepare table of contents as follows:

[image: sample]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=right,level distance=32pt}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree [.S [.Introduction ] [.Taxonomy
 ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Taxonomy}
\section{User Association}
\subsection{Subsection Header}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How much have you got so far? Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I tried using qtree, however I don't know how to add table of contents in qtree, thus, I thought MWE is no use here.

Comment: A MWE is always useful. And almost mandatory in your case, since we don't know anything about your document (i.e. documentclass, packages, etc.)

Comment: Ok, I'll add some that might be helpful.

Comment: @DG' , I added, please kindly check.

Comment: @Mithun: Your document has no `\section` etc. There is no tree to grow right now ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Added

Comment: @Mithun: Please use the mouse and mark the codes and press `CTRL-K` to format the code as such. I've removed the first 'example'

Comment: Thanks for adding the example. You've tagged this `qtree` but your code does not use that package. Instead, you seem to be using `tikz-qtree` there. These are quite different packages. For example, `qtree` is not based on Ti*k*Z or PGF at all.

Comment: What happens if your contents is too much for one page? What is the deepest sectional sub-division to be listed? (Is sub-section the deepest and section the topmost? So there are 2 levels involved?)

Comment: @cfr 2-levels. Assume that the content is enough for one page. I am flexible with any other packages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely shouldn't have tried to answer this ....

Proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{%
  subsection/.style={%
    delay n={%
      >O{n} %
    }{%
      for preceding siblings={do dynamics},
      temptoksa/.option=name,
      if nodewalk valid={previous}{%
        for previous={%
          if section={append/.register=temptoksa}{}%
        }%
      }{%
        replace by={[, coordinate, append]},
      },
    },
  },
  declare boolean={section}{0},
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\foresttoc{%
  \begingroup
    \xdef\foresttoctoc{}%
    \renewcommand\contentsline[3]{%
      \let\tempb\foresttoctoc
      \xdef\foresttoctoc{\tempb[{##2}, ##1]}%
    }%
    \renewcommand\numberline[1]{Sec.~##1 }%
    \bracketset{action character=@}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \begin{forest}
      before typesetting nodes={
        forked edges,
        for tree={
          grow'=0,
          anchor=parent,
          tier/.option=level,
        },
        where level=1{fork sep'=0pt}{},
      },
      [, coordinate,   @+\foresttoctoc  ]
    \end{forest}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\foresttoc
% \tableofcontents
\subsection{Awkward}
\section{User Association}
\subsection{Subsection Header}
\subsection{Subsection Header}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Taxonomy}
\section{User Association}
\subsection{Subsection Header}
\subsection{Subsection Header}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree-toc]

This allows - but no longer requires - you to have a regular table of contents, too. This is good because the desired format is pretty useless for locating things, something regular tables of contents do by design.

Comment: I am surprised that it takes you ~20 hours. :p

Comment: I'm surprised someone could even answer! This should deserve a bounty!

Comment: @CarLaTeX  definitely deserves. I don't have enough points to offer.

Comment: @Mithun I hope someone with > 20k will do it for us! I've already started too much bounties, recently :):):)

Comment: @Symbol1 I'm surprised you didn't write a package for it in the meantime ;).

Comment: @CarLaTeX I initially tried to just write out the tree correctly. That would have worked if I had a clue how to handle expansion, but I don't ... :(.

Comment: @Mithun Please see edited version above. A regular ToC is now permitted, but no longer required. (But we still use the `.toc` file and apparatus to collect the information etc.)